# IOS/Objective-C: NSPredicate against an NSNumber

Tags: ios, nspredicate, nsnumber

What is the correct syntax for filtering using an NSPredicate on an NSNumber value?

If checking against a variable, I believe I could do:

```
predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %d", [stdUserNumber intValue]];
```

In this case, I  want to check against absolute numbers either for equality or inequality as follows:

```
[predicateWithFormat:@"userid >=1"];
```

and also...

```
[predicateWithFormat:@"valid ==1"];//where 1 is an NSNumber representing a  boolean attribute in the model
```

Will this filter as expected?

Answer (score 0):

NSNumber is an object and you can write a predicate using object format :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %@", stdUserNumber];
```